# "I've found my way"

Tags: word-usage

Does it sound natural to your ears if someone says that he or she *found his/her way* meaning that he or she found his/her way of life? If not, is there maybe another way of saying this *shortly*, e.g. by a well-known idiom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common in the US to use that expression. It refers to the poetic notion that there are *paths* that one chooses in life, (like paths through the forest) so, "finding your way" is like "choosing the correct path."

Answer (score 2):

It sounds quite natural and makes perfect sense. You can also add "in life" to make it clear that you mean this.